# Como atualizar um jTable que exibe os dados do BD após cadastrar um novo item?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Possuo uma tabela (jTable) que exibe todos os dados cadastrados em um banco de dados. Minha tabela é preenchida sempre que a aplicação é iniciada através de um WindowEvent, porém quando efetuo um novo cadastro no banco de dados através de outro frame não consigo fazer com que meu jTable seja atualizado automaticamente para exibir também o novo registro cadastrado. Da maneira que está, o único jeito de visualizar os novos dados cadastrados no BD é encerrando a aplicação e iniciando-a novamente.

```
//Modelo da tabela
DefaultTableModel listalivros = new DefaultTableModel();

//Tabela que exibe os dados
 private JTable getJTable() {
    if (jTable == null) {
        jTable = new JTable(listalivros);
        jTable.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        listalivros.addColumn("ISBN");
        listalivros.addColumn("Título");
        listalivros.addColumn("Autor");
        listalivros.addColumn("Editora");
        listalivros.addColumn("Cosignação");
        listalivros.addColumn("Preço");
        listalivros.addColumn("Quantidade");
    }
    return jTable;
}

// Evento que preenche a tabela 
          public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
              System.out.println("windowOpened()"); // TODO Auto-generated
            listalivros.setNumRows(0);
              try {
                index.Executar("select * from livros");
                index.Resultado.next();
                rs = index.Resultado;
                do{
                    ISBN = (rs.getString("ISBN"));
                    TituloLivro = (rs.getString("titulo_livro"));
                    AutorLivro = (rs.getString("autor_livro"));
                    EditoraLivro = (rs.getString("editora_livro"));
                    Consignacao = (rs.getString("consignacao"));
                    Preco = (rs.getString("preco"));
                    Quantidade = (rs.getString("quantidade"));
                     listalivros.addRow(new Object[] { ISBN, TituloLivro,
                            AutorLivro, EditoraLivro, Consignacao, Preco,
                            Quantidade });
                }while (rs.next());
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar colocar seu método como `static` e chamar ele quando a inserção no BD for finalizada.

```
public static void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
```

A chama fica assim:

```
SuaClasse.windowOpened(null);
```

Outra opção é utilizar Threads para ficar atualizando a cada pouco tempo, de uma pesquisa no assunto, inclusive te recomendo este artigo:

http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/programacao-concorrente-e-threads/#17-1-threads

Comment: Consegui resolver criando um método static para atualizar minha jTable a cada cadastro.